# How to define a sortKey for DynamoDB?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

When I try to execute a query on a GSI on DynamoDB, the following error is reported:

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A query conditional requires a sort key to be present on the table or index being queried, yet none have been defined in the model**

What I should do in order to define this required sort key?
Here are some pieces of my code:

```
package com.test;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;

import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.mapper.annotations.*;

import java.time.Instant;

@Data
@Builder
@DynamoDbBean
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Accumulator {

    private Instant createdAt;
    private String userId;
    private String transactionIds;
    private String paymentAt;
    private String type;
    private Instant startAt;
    private Instant endAt;
    private Integer ordersTotal;
    private Integer retries;
    private String sortKey;

    @DynamoDbPartitionKey
    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    @DynamoDbSecondaryPartitionKey(indexNames= {"idx_by_payment_at"})
    @DynamoDbSortKey
    public String getPaymentAt() {
        return paymentAt.toString();
    }
}
```

Creating my table at DynamoDBConfig:

```
public DynamoDbAsyncTable<Accumulator> tableLocal(final DynamoDbEnhancedAsyncClient dynamoDbEnhancedAsyncClient) {
    var tableAccumulator = dynamoDbEnhancedAsyncClient.table(tablename, BeanTableSchema.create(Accumulator.class));
    try {
        tableAccumulator.createTable(CreateTableEnhancedRequest.builder()
            .provisionedThroughput(
                ProvisionedThroughput.builder()
                    .writeCapacityUnits(5L).readCapacityUnits(5L)
                    .build())
                .globalSecondaryIndices(
                    EnhancedGlobalSecondaryIndex.builder()
                        .indexName("idx_by_payment_at")
                        .projection(p -> p.projectionType(ProjectionType.KEYS_ONLY))
                        .provisionedThroughput(ProvisionedThroughput.builder()
                            .writeCapacityUnits(5L).readCapacityUnits(5L)
                            .build())
                        .build()
                )
            .build()).get();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        log.info("Skipping");
    }
    return tableAccumulator;
}
```

And my query:

```
    DynamoDbTable<Accumulator> table = dynamoDbEnhancedClient.table(tableName, TableSchema.fromBean(Accumulator.class));
    DynamoDbIndex<Accumulator> index = table.index("idx_by_payment_at");
    QueryConditional queryConditional = QueryConditional.sortBetween(
        Key.builder()
            .partitionValue("2022-01-23T06:10:12.948334Z")
            .build(),
        Key.builder()
            .partitionValue("2022-01-23T06:10:22.515769Z")
            .build());
    SdkIterable<Page<Accumulator>> query = index.query(queryConditional);
    List<Page<Accumulator>> pages = query.stream().toList();
    pages.forEach(page -> {
        List<Accumulator> accumulators = page.items();
        accumulators.stream().forEach(accumulator -> {
            System.out.println(accumulator);
        });
    });
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Check your GSI, it looks like you created it with `getPaymentAt()` as the partition key, not the sort key. Is `getUserId()` intended to be the partition key? Perhaps you wanted a local secondary index instead?

Comment: In other words: it's implied that you're trying to search transactions in range across all users, but that isn't clear. Please clarify your intent so we can help you define the index.

Comment: Hi, My intent is to query between 2 payment_at of one user and one type. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From OP comment:

> My intent is to query between 2 payment_at of one user and one type.

If that is the case, you'll need a GSI with

- a partition (hash) that is a combination of `user` and `type`;
- and a range (sort) that is the `payment_at`.

This will allow you to perform the access you require. The projection will depend on your use.

As it stands your primary table keys will allow you to select a range of `payment_at` for a given `user`. It might suffice to query that. Or it may be that you could use a sort key that is a compound of `type` and `payment_at`. The best choice really depends on your access patterns.